# Ошибки при билдинге проекта

Tags: ios, swift

Ошибки при билдинге проекта, который я получаю с SourceTree. Коллега по работе делает кое какие корректировки в проекте и выгружает в SourceTree, затем я получаю его и уже не могу запустить проект как я понял проблема с библиотеками, я через терминал указываю путь проекта и делаю `pod install`. Но это не помогает. Потом я иду в `Target` проекта затем в `General` и добавляю библиотеки в `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` тоже не помогает.

[image: Вот как выглядит сама ошибка]

Как вы выгружаете проекты в SourceTree с установленными Pod'ами ?

Comment: и что за корректировки?

Answer (score 1):

Удалите DerivedData: Window -> Projects, слева выделите проект и справа нажмите Delete.